# TuneError in Ray Module

Tags: pytorch, module, ray

I have been trying to use the below code snippet in Ray module to find the best model for my data. But I have been getting such error.

[Result I get after running the block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylNvc.png)

```
**TuneError**: ('Trials did not complete', [train_cifar_d2fed_00000, train_cifar_d2fed_00001, train_cifar_d2fed_00002, train_cifar_d2fed_00003, train_cifar_d2fed_00004, train_cifar_d2fed_00005, train_cifar_d2fed_00006, train_cifar_d2fed_00007, train_cifar_d2fed_00008, train_cifar_d2fed_00009, train_cifar_d2fed_00010, train_cifar_d2fed_00011, train_cifar_d2fed_00012, train_cifar_d2fed_00013, train_cifar_d2fed_00014, train_cifar_d2fed_00015, train_cifar_d2fed_00016, train_cifar_d2fed_00017, train_cifar_d2fed_00018, train_cifar_d2fed_00019, train_cifar_d2fed_00020, train_cifar_d2fed_00021, train_cifar_d2fed_00022, train_cifar_d2fed_00023, train_cifar_d2fed_00024])
```

Module versions

```
! pip install "ray[tune]==2.6.0"
! pip install "hyperopt==0.2.7"
! pip install "bayesian-optimization==1.3.1"
! pip install "tensorflow>=2.9.0"
! pip install numpy==1.19.5
! pip install fsspec
```

This is the code block I've been using.

```
def main(num_samples=10, max_num_epochs=10, gpus_per_trial=2):
    data_dir = resolve_path(r'D:\Machine learning in Device physics\GaN_AI-main\NN_Model\My Models')
    load_data(data_dir)

    config = {
        "l1": tune.choice([256,128,64]),
        "l2": tune.choice([8]),
        "l3": tune.choice([16]),
        "lr": tune.loguniform(1e-6, 1e-3),
        "batch_size": tune.choice([2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]),
    }
#     config = {
#         "l1": tune.choice([2**i for i in range(9)]),
#         "l2": tune.choice([2**i for i in range(7)]),
#         "l3": tune.choice([2**i for i in range(5)]),
#         "lr": tune.loguniform(1e-6, 1e-4),
#         "batch_size": tune.choice([4, 8, 16, 32]),
#     }
    scheduler = ASHAScheduler(
        metric="loss",
        mode="min",
        max_t=max_num_epochs,
        grace_period=1,
        reduction_factor=2,
    )
    result = tune.run(
        partial(train_cifar, data_dir=data_dir, max_num_epochs=max_num_epochs),
        resources_per_trial={"cpu": 18, "gpu": gpus_per_trial},
        config=config,
        num_samples=num_samples,
        scheduler=scheduler,
    )

    best_trial = result.get_best_trial("loss", "min", "last")
    print(f"Best trial config: {best_trial.config}")
    print(f"Best trial final validation loss: {best_trial.last_result['loss']}")
    #print(f"Best trial final validation accuracy: {best_trial.last_result['accuracy']}")

    best_trained_model = NeuralNetwork(best_trial.config["l1"], best_trial.config["l2"], best_trial.config["l3"])
    device = "cpu"
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        device = "cuda:0"
    #print(f"Using {device} device")
    best_trained_model.to(device)

    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(best_trial.checkpoint.to_directory(), "model.checkpoint")

    model_state, optimizer_state = torch.load(checkpoint_path)
    best_trained_model.load_state_dict(model_state)
    torch.save(best_trained_model, 'Ray_GaN_Best_NoOpt.pth')
    #test_acc = test_accuracy(best_trained_model, device)
    #print("Best trial test set accuracy: {}".format(test_acc))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # You can change the number of GPUs per trial here:
    main(num_samples=25, max_num_epochs=10, gpus_per_trial=1)
```

It will be very helpful if someone can help me with this error. Thanks in Advance

I tried to change the value of CPU and grace_period. But still not working